# Binomial coefficient sum involving floor function

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

Can the following summation be evaluated exactly (closed form)

$$\sum\limits_{j=-\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]}^{\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{j}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   p-nj  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}$$

Here [x] is the floor function.  If so, how? I tried egorychev but got tangled up with the residues and the floor function.

Comment: Can you elaborate your attempt? Also you can probably get pretty good asymptotic approximations for large p using Stirling - would that be of any use for you?

Comment: I determined several specific cases, and then attempted replacing the binomial coefficient with its residue respresentation.  But I'm certainly no expert at this method (or the method of coefficients) and i think i am handling the floor functions incorrectly.  The form of it looks innocent enough, which is why i thought i'd post out and see if anyone recognised it.

Comment: You haven't answered my second question, and you should consider adding your own attempts to the question in detail. What specific cases did you determine? What were the results? How are you handling the floor functions now? (So don't just reply in the comments, but elaborate your approach in the question.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose we seek to collect information concerning

$$\sum_{j=-\lfloor n/p\rfloor}^{\lfloor n/p\rfloor}
(-1)^j {2n\choose n-pj}.$$

We will construct a generating function in $n$ with $p\ge 1$ fixed.
We introduce

$${2n\choose n-pj} =
\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n-pj+1}} (1+z)^{2n}
\; dz.$$

Now as we examine this integral we see immediately that it vanishes if
$j\gt \lfloor  n/p\rfloor$ (pole  at zero disappears).   Moreover when
$j\lt -\lfloor n/p\rfloor$ we have that $[z^{n-pj}] (1+z)^{2n} = 0$ so
this vanishes  as well. Hence with  this integral in place  we may let
$j$ range from $-n$ to infinity and get

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{j=-n}^\infty (-1)^j z^{pj}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{1}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{n+1}} (1+z)^{2n}
\sum_{j=0}^\infty (-1)^{j-n} z^{pj-pn}
\; dz
\\ = \frac{(-1)^n}{2\pi i}
\int_{|z|=\epsilon} 
\frac{1}{z^{(p+1)n+1}} (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{1}{1+z^p}
\; dz.$$

We get zero for the residue at infinity, as can be seen from

$$\mathrm{Res}_{z=\infty} \frac{1}{z^{(p+1)n+1}} (1+z)^{2n}
\frac{1}{1+z^p}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} \frac{1}{z^2} z^{(p+1)n+1} 
\frac{(1+z)^{2n}}{z^{2n}} \frac{z^p}{1+z^p}
\\ = -\mathrm{Res}_{z=0} z^{(p-1)(n+1)}
(1+z)^{2n} \frac{1}{1+z^p} = 0.$$

With residues adding to zero and  introducing $\rho_k = \exp(\pi i/p +
2\pi i k/p)$ we thus obtain

$$-\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} (-1)^n \frac{1}{\rho_k^{(p+1)n+1}} (1+\rho_k)^{2n}
\frac{1}{p\rho_k^{p-1}}
= \frac{1}{p} \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} 
(-1)^n \frac{1}{\rho_k^{pn+n}} (1+\rho_k)^{2n}
\\ = \frac{1}{p} 
\sum_{k=0}^{p-1} \left(\frac{1}{\rho_k} + 2 + \rho_k\right)^n.$$

At this point we can compute a generating function using the fact that

$$\sum_{q\ge 0} \rho^q z^q = \frac{1}{1-\rho z}
= -\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{1}{z-1/\rho}$$

and we obtain as a first attempt

$$G_p(z) = \frac{1}{p} \sum_{k=0}^{p-1} 
\frac{1}{1-2(1+\cos(\pi/p + 2\pi k/p))z}.$$

Observe that this correctly represents  the cancelation of the pole at
$z=-1$ when  $p$ is  odd, contributing  zero when  $n\ge 1$  and $1/p$
otherwise. Furthermore note that with $\rho_k = \exp((2k+1)\pi i/p)$
we have

$$\frac{1}{\rho_{p-1-k}} = 
\exp(-(2(p-1-k)+1)\pi i/p) = \exp((2(k+1-p)-1)\pi i/p)
\\ = \exp((2(k+1)-1)\pi i/p - 2\pi i) = \exp((2k+1)\pi i/p) = \rho_k$$

so  the  poles  come in  pairs  with  no  pole  at $-1$  when  $p$  is
odd. Therefore the  set of poles generated by this  sum corresponds to
the first $(p-1)/2$ poles when $p$ is odd and the first $p/2$ when $p$
is even.  Joining these two we  get the degree of the denominator once
the sum is computed being $\lfloor p/2\rfloor.$

This first formula  enables us to compute a few  of these, like for
$p=8$ we get  (no complex number algebra  required, basic trigonometry
only)

$$G_8(z) = \frac{1 - 6 z + 10 z^2 - 4 z^3}
{1- 8 z + 20 z^2 - 16 z^3 + 2 z^4}.$$

Looking  up  the  coefficients  we  find  for  the  denominator  [OEIS
A034807](https://oeis.org/A034807)   and  for   the  numerator   [OEIS
A011973](https://oeis.org/A011973) which  point us  to three  types of
polynomials,  Fibonacci  polynomials,  Dickson polynomials  and  Lucas
polynomials. With these  data we are able to state  a *conjecture* for
the closed form of the generating function, which is

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
G_p(z) =
\left(\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor} 
\frac{p}{p-q} {p-q\choose q} (-1)^q z^q\right)^{-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor (p-1)/2\rfloor} {p-1-q\choose q} (-1)^q z^q.}$$

To verify this we must show that the poles are at

$$\left(\frac{1}{\rho_k} + 2 + \rho_k\right)^{-1}
\quad\text{with residue}\quad
-\frac{2}{p} \left(\frac{1}{\rho_k} + 2 + \rho_k\right)^{-1}$$

where the factor two appears because the poles have been paired.

We therefore require the generating  functions of the polynomials that
appear in  $G_p(z).$ Call the  numerator $A_p(z)$ and  the denominator
$B_p(z).$ We first compute the auxiliary generating function

$$Q_1(t, z) = \sum_{p\ge 0} t^p 
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor} {p-q\choose q} (-1)^q z^q
= \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q z^q 
\sum_{p\ge 2q} {p-q\choose q} t^p
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q z^q t^{2q}
\sum_{p\ge 0} {p+q\choose q} t^p
= \sum_{q\ge 0} (-1)^q z^q t^{2q} \frac{1}{(1-t)^{q+1}}
\\ = \frac{1}{1-t} \frac{1}{1+zt^2/(1-t)}
= \frac{1}{1-t+zt^2}.$$

We then have  $A(t, z) = t Q_1(t,  z).$ With $p/(p-q) = 1  + q/(p-q)$ we
get two pieces for $B(t, z)$, the  first is $Q_1(t, z)$ and the second
is

$$Q_2(t, z) = \sum_{p\ge 0} t^p 
\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor} {p-1-q\choose q-1} (-1)^q z^q
= \sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q z^q
\sum_{p\ge 2q} {p-1-q\choose q-1} t^p
\\ = \sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q z^q t^{2q}
\sum_{p\ge 0} {p+q-1\choose q-1} t^p
= \sum_{q\ge 1} (-1)^q z^q t^{2q}
\frac{1}{(1-t)^q}
\\ = -\frac{zt^2/(1-t)}{1+zt^2/(1-t)}
= -\frac{zt^2}{1-t+zt^2}$$

and hence we have $B(t, z) = Q_1(t, z) + Q_2(t, z).$
This yields the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\large
G_p(z) = \frac{[t^{p}] \frac{t}{1-t+zt^2}}
{[t^p] \frac{1-zt^2}{1-t+zt^2}}.}$$

Now introducing (we meet a  shifted generating function of the Catalan
numbers)

$$\alpha(z) = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4z}}{2}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\beta(z) = \frac{1-\sqrt{1-4z}}{2}$$

we have a relationship that is analogous to that between Fibonacci and
Lucas polynomials, namely,

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
A_p(z) = \frac{1}{\alpha(z)-\beta(z)}
(\alpha(z)^p - \beta(z)^p)
\quad\text{and}\quad
B_p(z) = \alpha(z)^p + \beta(z)^p.}$$

We now  verify that  $B_p(z) =  0$ for  $z$ a  value from  the claimed
poles.     Using    $1/(1/\rho_k+2+\rho_k)   =    \rho_k/(1+\rho_k)^2$
($\rho_k=-1$ is not included here) we find

$$\alpha(z) = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-4\rho_k/(1+\rho_k)^2}}{2}
= \frac{1+(1-\rho_k)/(1+\rho_k)}{2} = \frac{1}{1+\rho_k}$$

and similarly

$$\beta(z) = \frac{\rho_k}{1+\rho_k}.$$

Raising to the power $p$ we find

$$\alpha(z)^p + \beta(z)^p = \frac{1^p + \rho_k^p}{(1+\rho_k)^p}
= \frac{1-1}{(1+\rho_k)^p} = 0.$$

We have located  $\lfloor p/2\rfloor$ distinct zeros  here which means
given the degree  of $B_p(z)$ the poles are all  simple. This means we
may  evaluate  the  residue   by  setting  $z=\rho_k/(1+\rho_k)^2$  in
(differentiate the denominator)

$$\frac{1}{p} \left(\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor} 
\frac{1}{p-q} {p-q\choose q} (-1)^q q z^{q-1}\right)^{-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor (p-1)/2\rfloor} {p-1-q\choose q} (-1)^q z^q$$

which is

$$\frac{z}{p} \left(\sum_{q=1}^{\lfloor p/2\rfloor} 
{p-1-q\choose q-1} (-1)^q z^{q}\right)^{-1}
\sum_{q=0}^{\lfloor (p-1)/2\rfloor} {p-1-q\choose q} (-1)^q z^q$$

The numerator is $A_p(z)$ and we get

$$\frac{1+\rho_k}{1-\rho_k} \frac{2}{(1+\rho_k)^p}
= \frac{2}{(1-\rho_k)(1+\rho_k)^{p-1}}.$$

The denominator is $[t^p] Q_2(t, z)$ which is

$$[t^p] \frac{-zt^2}{1-t+zt^2} =
[t^p] \frac{1-zt^2}{1-t+zt^2}  - [t^p] \frac{1}{1-t+zt^2}
\\ = [t^p] \frac{1-zt^2}{1-t+zt^2}  
- [t^{p+1}] \frac{t}{1-t+zt^2} = B_p(z) - A_{p+1}(z) = -A_{p+1}(z).$$

We get

$$- \frac{1+\rho_k}{1-\rho_k} 
\frac{1^{p+1}-\rho_k^{p+1}}{(1+\rho_k)^{p+1}}
= -\frac{(1+\rho_k)^2}{(1-\rho_k)(1+\rho_k)^{p+1}}
= -\frac{1}{(1-\rho_k)(1+\rho_k)^{p-1}}.$$

Joining  numerator and  denominator and  multiplying by  $z/p$ finally
produces

$$ \frac{1}{p} \left(\frac{1}{\rho_k} + 2 + \rho_k\right)^{-1}
\frac{2/(1-\rho_k)/(1+\rho_k)^{p-1}}
{-1/(1-\rho_k)/(1+\rho_k)^{p-1}}
= -\frac{2}{p} \left(\frac{1}{\rho_k} + 2 + \rho_k\right)^{-1}$$

as claimed. We have proved that  the formula from the Egorychev method
matches  the  conjectured  form  in   terms  of  a  certain  class  of
polynomials that  are related  to Fibonacci  and Lucas  polynomials as
well as Catalan numbers.

Comment: This is extremley helpful.  Thank you very much.  I can see where my attempts were failing with regard to the floor functions.  Your choice of terminals on the summation, -n to infinity, implies some overall strategy, which i admit i don't understand within the egorychev method.  Is there a way to know whether the method will yeild a closed form result vs a summation identity etc?

Comment: Achieving an algorithmic form of the Egorychev method remains an interesting challenge I believe. One thing to keep in mind is that when infinite series appear they have to converge in the chosen annulus for the corresponding integral (a condition that does not appear with finite sums). Sometimes as seen above an integral correctly enforces the range of the summation index, which leaves us a choice of terminals that is most convenient for the computation.

Comment: Indeed.  In the spirit of the forum i will post one attempt at the summation i did a while ago, and you will see why you got the generating functions relating to the polynomials you found.  It will also illustrate my ignorance with the method in regards to my question in my previous comment, regarding strategy (i.e. when will the method yeild a closed form and not just an identity).

Comment: Could you make this an answer rather than including it in the question statement?

Comment: Sorry Marko I'm not really up with the etiquette of the forum. I actually did attempt to add it as an answer but it gave me a message informing me to edit my original post...Am I right in saying that you think I should cut and paste it as an answer?

Comment: I suggest you remove it from the question statement and post it as an answer, thereby adding structure and improving readability. Group the different steps of your computation into paragraphs and state your objective for each and how you plan to achieve it. Write an introduction and include references for the statements you do not prove. I do not claim to be able to follow what you are doing but this way you raise your chances of finding a reader who does. In its present shape it is not all that conducive to producing useful feedback.

Comment: Ok. I have re-formatted as per your suggestions.  I hope now it is a bit easier to understand.  Either way your contribution has been very valuable to me.

Comment: $\displaystyle +1$. Wow !!!. You are our Egorychev Master.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**  The following material is in response to the answer and comments from Marko.  It is included here to illustrate my lack of understanding as to when the egorychev method will yield a closed form rather than a summation identity as well as to provide some background information as requested by TMM.

For some background to this problem first consider the origin of the summation.  Consider therefore the summation
$$h\left( n,p \right)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}{{}}{{\cos }^{2p}}\left( \frac{\pi (2j+1)}{2n} \right)$$
The aim is to obtain a closed form for the sum.  From recent work I know that these summations can be converted to finite summations involving binomial coefficients.  The advantage of this form over the trigonometric form lies in the fact that over certain ranges of parameters the summation takes on very simple closed forms.  For a physics example where this is useful see https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09317.
In what follows I will use the method outlined in the afore mentioned arxiv paper.  The approach first involves writing the trigonometric power as a binomial expansion, i.e.
$$h\left( n,p \right)=\frac{1}{{{2}^{2p}}}{{\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}{\left( {{e}^{i\frac{\pi (2j+1)}{2n}}}+{{e}^{-i\frac{\pi (2j+1)}{2n}}} \right)}}^{2p}}=\frac{1}{{{2}^{2p}}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2p}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   k  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}{{{e}^{i\frac{\pi (2j+1)}{n}\left( p-k \right)}}}}$$
Evaluating the geometric series and then equating real and imaginary components yields

$$h\left( n,p \right)=\frac{1}{{{2}^{2p+1}}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2p}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   k  \\
\end{matrix} \right)\frac{\sin \left( \left( k-p \right)2\pi  \right)}{\sin \left( \frac{\left( k-p \right)}{n}\pi  \right)}}$$
Now observe that 
$$\frac{\sin \left( \left( k-p \right)2\pi  \right)}{\sin \left( \frac{\left( k-p \right)}{n}\pi  \right)}=0$$ 
for $k-p\ne qn$ and 
$$\frac{\sin \left( \left( k-p \right)2\pi  \right)}{\sin \left( \frac{\left( k-p \right)}{n}\pi  \right)}=\underset{z\to qn}{\mathop{\lim }}\,\frac{\sin \left( z2\pi  \right)}{\sin \left( \frac{z}{n}\pi  \right)}=\frac{2\pi \cos \left( 2q\pi  \right)}{\frac{\pi }{n}\cos \left( q\pi  \right)}={{\left( -1 \right)}^{q}}2n$$ for $k-p=qn$.  Consider then the case when $p<n$, then the only singularity occurs when k=p.  For that case we have
$$h\left( n,p \right)=\frac{n}{{{2}^{2p}}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   p  \\
\end{matrix} \right)$$
This is a preview that the summation will take on simple forms for various restrictions on p.  The fact that the summand vanishes for various k, implies that we need to come up with a counting scheme for the singularities.  Note for $p\ge n$ singularities are introduced at every multiple of n and for k=p, i.e, $k-p=mn$.  In fact if $qn\le p<\left( q+1 \right)n$ there are 2q+1 singularities.  The total number of singularities is therefore $2\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]+1$.  Now consider the example when p=qn.  In this case the singularities occur at k=mn where  m runs from 0 to $2\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]$.  However if $qn\le p<\left( q+1 \right)n$, i.e. $p=qn+L$ say, singularities are shifted from a multiple of n.   Hence we have singularities occurring at $k=mn+L$, where $L=p-qn=p-n\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]$.   noting
$$\frac{\sin \left( \left( k-p \right)2\pi  \right)}{\sin \left( \frac{\left( k-p \right)}{n}\pi  \right)}={{\left( -1 \right)}^{q}}2n={{\left( -1 \right)}^{m-\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]}}2n$$  since  $$k-p=qn\Rightarrow q=\left[ \frac{k-p}{n} \right]=\left[ \frac{mn+L-p}{n} \right]=\left[ \frac{mn+p-n\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]-p}{n} \right]=\left[ m-\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right] \right]=m-\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]$$
 We have therefore (where the counting index m is replaced by k)
$$h\left( n,p \right)=\frac{n}{{{2}^{2p}}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{2\left[ p/n \right]}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k+\left[ p/n \right]}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   kn+p-n\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}$$
(since all other terms are zero).  Now observe we may write
$$h\left( n,p \right)=\frac{n}{{{2}^{2p}}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left[ p/n \right]}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k+\left[ p/n \right]}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   kn+p-n\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}+\frac{n}{{{2}^{2p}}}\sum\limits_{k=\left[ p/n \right]+1}^{2\left[ p/n \right]}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k+\left[ p/n \right]}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   kn+p-n\left[ \frac{p}{n} \right]  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}$$
So
$$h\left( n,p \right)=\frac{n}{{{2}^{2p}}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\left[ p/n \right]}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   -kn+p  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}+\frac{n}{{{2}^{2p}}}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\left[ p/n \right]}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k+2\left[ p/n \right]}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   kn+p  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}$$
Hence 
$$h\left( n,p \right)=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}{{{\cos }^{2p}}\left( \frac{\pi (2j+1)}{2n} \right)}=\frac{n}{{{2}^{2p}}}\sum\limits_{k=-\left[ p/n \right]}^{\left[ p/n \right]}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   p-kn  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}$$
Which is the summation in my original post.  While the binomial form obviously yields nice closed forms for the trigonometric summation when bounds on p with respect to n are known, I have a certain application in mind in which it would be advantageous for a closed form for arbitrary p.  Hence the question: Can a closed form for the summation be found using the Egorychev method (or method of coefficients)?
Not being an expert at such things I simply went ahead and performed the following calculation:
Let p be a multiple of n, i.e. let p=Qn, for integer Q, then we have
$$\sum\limits_{k=-\left[ p/n \right]}^{\left[ p/n \right]}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2p  \\
   p-kn  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}=\sum\limits_{j=-Q}^{Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{j}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2nQ  \\
   n\left( Q-j \right)  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}=\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q-j}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2nQ  \\
   nj  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}$$
Observe from $\left( \begin{matrix}
   n  \\
   k  \\
\end{matrix} \right)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\left| z \right|=\delta }^{{}}{\frac{{{\left( 1+z \right)}^{n}}}{{{z}^{k+1}}}dz}$ then one has
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q-j}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2nQ  \\
   nj  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}=\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q}}}{2\pi i}\int\limits_{\left| z \right|=\delta }^{{}}{\frac{{{\left( 1+z \right)}^{2nQ}}\left( 1+{{z}^{n\left( 1+2Q \right)}} \right)}{\left( {{z}^{n}}+1 \right){{z}^{1-n+n\left( 1+2Q \right)}}}dz}$$
As can be verified by calculating the residues.  In the form above the finite summation has been evaluated.  And this is where my ignorance of the strategy of this method comes to the fore.  Note that the above contour integral (I think) yields no advantage in terms of a closed form, and so I pressed ahead and chose a specific representation, namely 
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q-j}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2nQ  \\
   nj  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}=\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q}}{{2}^{2nQ}}}{\pi }\int\limits_{0}^{\pi }{\frac{{{\cos }^{2nQ}}\left( \theta  \right)}{\cos \left( n\theta  \right)}\cos \left( n\left( 1+2Q \right)\theta  \right)d\theta }$$
Continuing with the calculation consider therefore
$$\frac{\cos \left( n\left( 1+2Q \right)\arccos \left( x \right) \right)}{\cos \left( n\arccos \left( x \right) \right)}=\frac{{{T}_{n\left( 1+2Q \right)}}\left( x \right)}{{{T}_{n}}\left( x \right)}$$
where T are the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.  Note: ${{T}_{j}}{{T}_{k}}=\frac{1}{2}\left( {{T}_{k+j}}+{{T}_{\left| k-j \right|}} \right)$  hence
${{T}_{n}}{{T}_{2Qn}}=\frac{1}{2}\left( {{T}_{2Qn+n}}+{{T}_{2Qn-n}} \right)$.
From this one obtains a recurrence relationship that eventuates in a summation over the polynomials; namely
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q-j}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2nQ  \\
   nj  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}=\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q}}{{2}^{2nQ+1}}}{\pi }\int\limits_{-1}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{2nQ}}}{\sqrt{1-{{x}^{2}}}}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{Q}{{{\varepsilon }_{k}}{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}{{T}_{2n\left( Q-k \right)}}\left( x \right)}dx}$$
where ${{\varepsilon }_{k}}=1\,\,\left( k\ne Q \right)\,\,\frac{1}{2}\,\,\left( k=Q \right)\,$.  Now Chebyshev polynomials of even index are even functions, therefore
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q-j}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2nQ  \\
   nj  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}=\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q}}{{2}^{2nQ+1}}}{\pi }2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{Q}{{{\varepsilon }_{k}}{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}}\int\limits_{0}^{1}{\frac{{{x}^{2nQ}}{{T}_{2n\left( Q-k \right)}}\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-{{x}^{2}}}}dx}$$
Consider the following integral the derivation of which will not be reproduced here (See for example Gradshteyn 7.346)
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{x}^{s-1}}\frac{{{T}_{n}}\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-{{x}^{2}}}}dx}=\frac{\pi }{s{{2}^{s}}B\left( \tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}s+\tfrac{1}{2}n,\tfrac{1}{2}+\tfrac{1}{2}s-\tfrac{1}{2}n \right)}$$ 
We have therefore
$$\int\limits_{0}^{1}{{{x}^{2nQ+1-1}}\frac{{{T}_{2n\left( Q-k \right)}}\left( x \right)}{\sqrt{1-{{x}^{2}}}}dx}=\frac{\pi }{\left( 2nQ+1 \right){{2}^{2nQ+1}}B\left( 1+2nQ-nk,1+nk \right)}$$
Hence
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q-j}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2nQ  \\
   nj  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}=\frac{2{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q}}}{2nQ+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}{{\varepsilon }_{k}}\frac{\Gamma \left( 2nQ+2 \right)}{\Gamma \left( 1+2nQ-nk \right)\Gamma \left( 1+nk \right)}}$$
or
$$\sum\limits_{j=0}^{2Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q-j}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2nQ  \\
   nj  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}=2\sum\limits_{j=0}^{Q}{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{Q-j}}{{\varepsilon }_{k}}\left( \begin{matrix}
   2nQ  \\
   nj  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}$$
This however is a trivial consequence of the symmetry of the coefficients.  So while not a closed form, it did yield a trivial identity (in a very longwinded way).  Such calculations (I have a few others) also deliver identities.  Yet I see the application of the method to other problems yielding closed form solutions to binomial summations.  This then prompted my questions in the comments regarding the strategy of the method.  It should be noted that Marko’s answer, while not strictly a solution to my question, provided valuable insight into the method and to this specific summation (via the generating function).